# Check if sql query column has certain data using PHP

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, if-statement

I'm working with an external database in Wordpress and trying to use an IF statement if a column has a certain value. So the column 'period' will have the value of either 'week', 'month' or 'year'. I want to be able to change the data based on that. Am I headed in the right direction? Any help appreciated.

```
$recurring_events = $events_db->get_results(
    "
    SELECT gc_event_id, period
    FROM gc_event_recurring
    WHERE gc_event_id = '$masterID'
    "
);

foreach ($recurring_events as $recurring_event) :
if ($recurring_events['period'] === 'month') { <-- NEED HELP HERE

// Do Something

} else if ($recurring_events['period'] === 'year') {

// Do Something

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `get_results` returns objects instead of arrays. It also looks like you're referencing `$recurring_events` where you should be referencing `$recurring_event`.

Try using this line instead within the foreach, where you said you need help:

```
if ($recurring_event->period === 'month') {
```

Comment: Yup, haha. I don't know why I was trying to make it so hard for myself. Thanks!